# stripping down info from imdb using HttpWebRequest ,but when a ÅöØ comes along i get ugly output, how to fix?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code in c#, using winforms!
I've tested ENCODING UTF8 and all others that i have. Same result.

DIRECTOR-Måns.Mårlind,.Björn.Stein]

from the movie http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1496025/

```cs
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.UTF8, true);
string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
resp.Close();
return sourceCode;
```

Comment: Define "ugly output" -- maybe a screenshot?

Comment: i cant add image no "points jet"  -[DIRECTOR-M&#xE5;ns.M&#xE5;rlind,.Bj&#xF6;rn.Stein]

Comment: You'll need to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() on the string.

Comment: sourceCode = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(sourceCode);   added this, and it takes out the bad carracters, but dont replace with ones actually on site